# Android App not Autoresizing in different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following android view layout which should appear in a tabular layout 4 Floating Action Buttons and 4 Text Views that should appear below each the floating action buttons :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/background">




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_view_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/qck_notification"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_notification"
            android:layout_marginRight="130dp"
            android:maxHeight="2dp"
            >
        </android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/qck_reports"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_file_chart" />


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_view_layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">



        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/qck_about"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_notification"
            android:layout_marginRight="130dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/qck_locate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_map_marker" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="About Us"
        android:id="@+id/txt_about_us"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_view_layout2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Locate Us"
        android:id="@+id/txt_locate_us"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_view_layout2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Notifications"
        android:id="@+id/txt_notifications"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_view_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Reports n Queries"
        android:id="@+id/txt_reports_n_queries"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_view_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/main_view_layout2" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The above screen appears very well in a 5 inch screen but when I try to view it on a tablet.  The  appearance becomes distorted and this is especially the  textviews on the far right side.(Reports n Queried and Locate Us). I need help on how  I can  auto resize it so that it can fit very well in different screens?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest modifying your existing layout in another xml file. You can make different xml files to be used on different screen sizes.

[Here is a link to more information.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)